# Rails 3 Problem with routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have a haml link that looks like this

```
=link_to "accept", friendship, :method => :put
```

and i am trying to map "put" to use the "update" action in my controller

in my routes like so

```
resources :friendships do
   collection do
    get :create
    delete :destroy
    put :update
   end
 end
```

so if i use method "get" it should get a new friend (that works), if i delete then the "destroy" action is used and if i put the "update" action gets used.

I take it I am doing this completely wrong somehow.

my "create" friend link looks like this

```
=link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => provider), :method => :post
```

and this is my whole friends.haml

```
.profile
  .providers
    %h1 Other Users
    - @providers.each do |provider|
      %p
        =provider.login
        =link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => provider), :method =>         
:post
  .friends
    %h1 Friends
    - @friends.each do |friendship|
      %p
        =friendship.friend.login
        =link_to "remove", friendship, :method => :delete
        =link_to "message", memos_path(:other_user => friendship.friend)

  .friends-out
    %h1 Friends Out
    - @friends_out.each do |friendship|
      %p
        =friendship.friend.login
        =link_to "remove", friendship, :method => :delete

  .friends-in
    %h1 Friends In
    - @friends_in.each do |friendship|
      %p
        =friendship.friend.login
        =link_to "remove", friendship, :method => :delete
        =link_to "accept", friendship, :method => :put
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're almost doing right, but your doing it the wrong way. You should do like this:

```
resources :friendships
```

No more, no less, that's it. Because when you use resources, it will by default map the put protocol to the update action, it will map the delete protocol to the destroy action, and it will map the POST protocol to the create action. Because you should not use GET when the database is somehow changed (create, update, destroy).

And when you use the link_to helper, try it like this:

```
=link_to "accept", friendship_path(@friendship), :method => :put
```

Edit:

Also make sure you have the default javascript included to handle the specified method of posting:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Comment: <%= link_to "accept", friendship, :method => :put %> will work as I think friendship is the object of same class. ( In short I think he is running a loop)

Comment: yes i'm in a loop of friends, i'm sorry i left that detail out

Comment: Yeah, if friendship is the instance, it would of course work.

Comment: i get this error when i map it (add friend) how you said it tho?

Unknown action

The action 'index' could not be found for FriendshipsController

Comment: Does that happen when you click the link described above?

Comment: yeah the first link_to is basically what you showed me except in a loop, i've update my post to reflect my friends.haml file.

Comment: Very good description now. But just so I know, does the remove link work but not the accept link?

Comment: the "add" friend tells me the index action does not exist.
"remove" tells me the show action doesn't exist
and "accept" also tells me that.

Comment: Seems like there is nothing to change the method when the link is clicked. I edited my answer to include the necessary javascript needed for that to work.